# Curious behavior with csvwrite and writing dates

Tags: matlab, csv, io, output

When writing numbers into `.csv` in Matlab, it seems to modify the data.
This is alarming to me, something I have never seen before.

```
>> csvwrite('FirstCol.csv',[201210;201211])    
>> twodates =csvread('FirstCol.csv')    
twodates =    
      201210
      201210
```

Now  compare with `xlswrite`

```
>> xlswrite('FirstCol.xls',[201210;201211])    
>> aa=xlsread('FirstCol.xls')    
aa =    
      201210
      201211
```

Could the reason be some automatic formatting underneath date-similar numbers? (My explanation is just mystcism)

Comment: Thanks! Missed it! Case closed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`csvwrite` documentation](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html)

> `csvwrite` writes a maximum of five significant digits. If you need greater precision, use [`dlmwrite`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) with a precision argument.

So doing:

```
csvwrite('FirstCol.csv',[201210;201211])
csvread('FirstCol.csv')
```

you do indeed lose the final digit.

But by using `dlmwrite`, you can do

```
dlmwrite('FirstCol.csv',[201210;201211],'precision',6)
dlmread('FirstCol3.csv')
```

which does indeed result in the correct output.

I am using a Mac and I can't use `xlswrite`, but obviously that is a reasonable method as well.